# Tensors transformation

Tags: python, tensorflow

Am trying to use `tf.gather_nd(params, indices, name=None)` to retrieve elements from a feature map tensor

Is there anyway to transform this tensor `[[0,2,2]]` to `[[0,0],[1,2],[2,2]]`
As I need it to use it as indices in the function

I only have `[[0,2,2]]`

it should be this structure

```
indices = [[0,0],[1,2],[2,2]]
params = [['3', '1','2','-1'], ['0.3', '1.4','5','0'],['5', '6','7','8']]

t=tf.gather_nd(params, indices, name=None)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(sess.run(t)) # outputs 3 5 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to transform the tensor `t0 = [[x0, x1, x2, ... xn]]` into the tensor `[[0, x0], [1, x1], [2, x2], ..., [n, xn]]`, you can concatenate it with a range tensor as follows:

```
t0 = ...
N = tf.shape(t0)[1]                   # number of indices
t0 = tf.concat([tf.range(N), t0], 0)  # [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2]]
indices = tf.transpose(t0)            # [[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

This should give you the indices you want.

Comment: You can achieve the same result by using `tf.stack` in one line as below

`tf.stack((tf.range(N), t0[0]), axis=1)`